# How does Phonegap/Cordova notify Android that page is loaded?

Tags: android, cordova

Is there an equivalent to this for android please?

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotification:[NSNotification notificationWithName:CDVPageDidLoadNotification object:self.webView]];
```

Edit:

This is the CordovaActivity.java

```
private boolean displayAd = false; 

    public void setDisplayAd(boolean displayAd) {

    this.displayAd = displayAd;
    Log.d("SomeTag" , displayAd?"true":"false");

}

public boolean getDisplayAd() {
    return this.displayAd;
} 

public Object onMessage(String id, Object data) {
    if (!"onScrollChanged".equals(id)) {
        LOG.d(TAG, "onMessage(" + id + "," + data + ")");

    }

    if("onPageStarted".equals(id)) {
        setDisplayAd(true);
        LOG.d(TAG, "TRUE");
    }
     return null;}
```

And in my Main Activity I am calling displayAd method in my onResume:

`public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        displayAd();
}`

And my displayAd Method:

```
private void displayAd() {
      if(super.getDisplayAd()){
        buildAd();
        mInterstitialAd.show();
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Ad loaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        setDisplayAd(false);
        Log.d("Hello", displayAd ? "true" : "false");
    } else {
        setDisplayAd(true);
        Log.d("Hello1", displayAd ? "true" : "false");
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Ad NOT loaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

Comment: so you edited the CordovaActivity.java directly?

Comment: Yes is that wrong? I added the global variable, getDisplayAd() and setDisplayAd() and the If statement inside the onMessage method

Comment: and did you clean and rebuild the projects after that? (first the cordovaLib project and then your current project) It usually don't pick the changes on a project library

Comment: Yes I did a clean and rebuild still nothing

Comment: are your new logs being printed? I've just tested on a sample project, adding new log messages, and mine are being printed

Comment: I have an HTML button and when clicked it performs window.location.reload(); Messages are being Printed "TRUE" & "FALSE" every time the page is reloaded but the variable displayAd is not being changed onPageStarted from false to true. In my method displayAd(); I am checking whether this.getDisplayAd() is true or false. If true I want it to show the add(after page is reloaded) if it is still false I want it to just show Ad NOT loaded

Comment: try with super.getDisplayAd(), as the variable changed is the one in CordovaActivity.java, not on your main activity. And other thing I see, when you check the "onPageStarted", you set the displayAd to true, but onMessage is called a lot of times, and every time the id isn't "onPageStarted" (your else part) it changes to false, put a log inside  setDisplayAd to check if it is changing to true and then change to false in the else part

Comment: Yes you are right, with the if statement shown above it's logging: true, false,false,false when the page is first started. As the reload button is pressed it's logging: false, true, false, false. Is there a work around this please?

Comment: don't set to false on the else, set it to false when/where you show the ad

Comment: Hi I did that and it's now setting setDisplayAd() to false after the Ad is shown. But As I reload the page The Ad is still not showing. displayAd() is being called from my onResume. I edited my question specifically my displayAd() and if("onPageStarted"). Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: try with super.setDisplayAd(false); on your displayAd()

Comment: It's Logging: Hello1: true, Hello: false, Hello1: true but still no Ad load on page reload

Comment: You only have the  displayAd() on the onResume(), I don't think  onResume() is called on page reload, why don't you show the add whey you receive the "onPageFinished"?

Comment: and how do i check for onPageFinished in my main Activity please?

Comment: try adding the whole public Object onMessage(String id, Object data) method to your main activity, with an @Override over it

Comment: I tried that but still can't figure out a way to call the onPageFinished from CordovaWebViewClient.java

Comment: see my edited answer, I've added all the code from onMessage and an onPageFinished example. You have to put it inside your main activity, with the @Override, so the onMessage executed is the one on your activity an not the one on CordovaActivity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On android, the class `CordovaWebViewClient` do a `this.appView.postMessage("onPageFinished", url);` when it finish loading the page

But listening to it isn't as easy as on iOS

CordovaInterface has a method `public Object onMessage(String id, Object data);`

Your main activity should be extending `CordovaActivity`, and as `CordovaActivity` implements `CordovaInterface`, you could override the `public Object onMessage(String id, Object data)` from `CordovaActivity` from your main activity, but I'm not sure if that's a good idea.

To override the onMessage , copy the whole onMessage from `CordovaActivity` and paste it on your main activity, be aware that the onMessage from `CordovaActivity` won't be executed anymore.

```
    @Override
    public Object onMessage(String id, Object data) {
        if (!"onScrollChanged".equals(id)) {
            LOG.d(TAG, "overrided onMessage(" + id + "," + data + ")");
        }

        if("onPageFinished".equals(id)) {

            //Show the ad here

        }

        if ("splashscreen".equals(id)) {
            if ("hide".equals(data.toString())) {
                this.removeSplashScreen();
            }
            else {
                // If the splash dialog is showing don't try to show it again
                if (this.splashDialog == null || !this.splashDialog.isShowing()) {
                    String splashResource = preferences.getString("SplashScreen", null);
                    if (splashResource != null) {
                        splashscreen = getResources().getIdentifier(splashResource, "drawable", getClass().getPackage().getName());
                    }
                    this.showSplashScreen(this.splashscreenTime);
                }
            }
        }
        else if ("spinner".equals(id)) {
            if ("stop".equals(data.toString())) {
                this.spinnerStop();
                this.appView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
        else if ("onReceivedError".equals(id)) {
            JSONObject d = (JSONObject) data;
            try {
                this.onReceivedError(d.getInt("errorCode"), d.getString("description"), d.getString("url"));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else if ("exit".equals(id)) {
            this.endActivity();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Hi I have added a global variable in my Cordova Activity private boolean displayAd = false; and `if("onPageStarted".equals(id)) {
            setDisplayAd(true);
            LOG.d(TAG, "TRUE");
        }
        else {
            setDisplayAd(false);
            LOG.d(TAG, "FALSE");
        }` and this if statement to change the variable onPageStarted. In my main Activity I have `if(this.getDisplayAd()){
mInterstitialAd.show();  } else {           Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Ad NOT loaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }` variable never being changed to true. Any insight please?

Comment: These are my setDisplayAd and getDisplayAd `public void setDisplayAd(boolean displayAd) {

        this.displayAd = displayAd;

    }

    public boolean getDisplayAd() {
        return this.displayAd;
    }`

Comment: Edit your question and add all the code you use for checking the if("onPageStarted".equals(id)) so I can take a look

Comment: Thank you. This is what I'm actually looking for.  Working Charm.. Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 0):

With using plugin "device"

```
var app = {
    initialize: function () {
        this.bindEvents();

    },
    bindEvents: function () {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
        //this.onDeviceReady();
    },
    // deviceready Event Handler
    //
    // The scope of 'this' is the event. In order to call the 'receivedEvent'
    // function, we must explicitly call 'app.receivedEvent(...);'
    onDeviceReady: function () {
        app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
    },
    receivedEvent: function (id) {
        if ('deviceready' == id) {
            StatusBar.overlaysWebView(false);
            this.prepareDB();
        }
        console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi I have already installed the plugin. What I am trying to do is display an Interstitial when the user clicks an HTML button. Currently the Interstitial is loading when the app is opened and the onCreate is called but I cannot seem to replicate this on button click. This is my onCreate method                        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);super.init();  loadUrl(launchUrl);initAd();startGame();
mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener(){
public void onAdLoaded(){
displayAd();
}
});
}

Comment: Hi! All element binding must be after init event raised